# Cross-platform development on a single PC

Tags: operating-systems, cross-platform

I'm a Windows user/developer itching to start diving into the *NIX world and Mac OS software development. What software (both paid and free) would allow me to install/easily run other OS (Linux, Mac OS X, Unix, whatever) all on the same machine.

I'm willing to upgrade my computer (8GB of RAM, 8-core) if needed be.

If you could point me to a link of simple tutorial / book that'd be great so I could study on my own.

Comment: **Dual Quad Core?** Are you rich? ;-)

Comment: Wow, it's been almost a decade, and now I'm now fully well versed in both *Nix (Ubuntu) and macOS (owning a Macbook Pro laptop) system. And yes, now I run all *3* on my Mac laptop via Parallels. :grin: What a strange journey it's been.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate to say this, but if money isn't a concern for you (it doesn't sound like it), I'd recommend buying a Mac and running Windows and Linux inside virtual machines (such as VirtualBox). There is no legal or reliable way of running Mac OS X on a PC, especially if you plan on doing development for it. On the other hand, a Mac can run all three operating systems simultaneously.

*Disclaimer: I'm not trying to sound like a Mac fanboy; in fact, I actually prefer Windows. However, for your situation, I think it's the only real way to go.*

Comment: @musicfreak: thank you for your insight. sounds like a good way to go.

Comment: You don't even have to buy a high-end Mac. A Mac mini would probably do what you need.

Comment: @Sasha, almost a decade later, yes, I'm running all 3 on my Macbook Pro laptop. ;-).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking at virtualization software such as VirtualBox. That will let you install other OS without totally leaving your familiar windows environment behind. You will loose a bit of performance, but on modern systems that's not a big concern, and certainly not for what you're saying you have.

For MacOS, the only legal way for you to do it is to buy a Mac, though there have been reports of success in installing MacOS under virtualization software.